# how to send data with click event in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have this simple example written in Vue.js.

```js
// vue instance
var vm = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
        matrix: ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""],
    },
    methods: {
        handleClick: function() {
            console.log("event triggered");
        }
    }
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#game-box {
  width: 150px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 0px;
  background: green;
}

.grid-item {
  float: left;
  width: 33.333%;
  height: 50px;
  background: yellow;
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div id="game-box">
    <div v-for="(sign, index) in matrix" class="grid-item" @click="handleClick">
      {{ sign }}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there any way to send data with click event (for example the index of the element that was clicked) in order to be handled by the `handleClick` method doing something like this:

```
handleClick: function(index) {
    console.log(index);
}
```

Comment: `@click="handleClick(index)` should work, have you tried this way? working example https://jsfiddle.net/azs06/4ps1b4nk/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following snippet will pass index to your handleClick function.

`handleClick(index)`

```js
// vue instance
var vm = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
        matrix: ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""],
    },
    methods: {
        handleClick: function(i) {
            console.log("event triggered", i);
        }
    }
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#game-box {
  width: 150px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 0px;
  background: green;
}

.grid-item {
  float: left;
  width: 33.333%;
  height: 50px;
  background: yellow;
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div id="game-box">
    <div v-for="(sign, index) in matrix" class="grid-item" @click="handleClick(index)">
      {{ sign }}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The use of an arrow / anonymous function is unnecessary. A simple `handleClick(index)` will do.

Comment: Ah yep, I assumed it would call that function on load. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
// in view
@click='handleClick(data)'


// in logic
methods: {
handleClick(dataFromClick) => {
// do something with dataFromClick
}
}
```